# setter and getter for an atomic property

Tags: objective-c, properties, atomic, getter-setter

what's the auto-gen'd getter and setter look like for the following property value?

```
... in .h
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
    NSString *_value;
}

@property(retain) NSString *value;

... in .m
@synthesize value = _value;
```

what if I change the property to be

```
@property(retain, readonly) NSString *value;
```

specifically I am interested in the atomic part of the story, plus the retain, and if possible, detailed code would be more clear as to what's going exactly going on behind the scene.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Atomic vs nonatomic properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They would look something like:

```
- (NSString*) value 
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        return [[_value retain] autorelease];
    }
}

- (void) setValue:(NSString*)aValue
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [aValue retain];
        [_value release];
        _value = aValue;
    }
}
```

If you change the property to readonly, no setter is generated.  The getter will be identical.

Comment: great! what if the property is @property (copy) NSString *value?

Comment: Actually, I believe the setter would actually use the `if (aValue != value){ [aValue release] ; [value retain] ; value = aValue }` way of doing it.

Comment: Also - and this is more important - the lock is not the object's lock, but a lightweight lock just for the property.  This means another method can't guarantee thread safety of the property by just synchronising on the object.

Comment: custom setter with @synchronized(self) is several factors slower than an atomic property's autosynthesized setter

Comment: What would you recommend @LearnCocos2D?

Comment: @W.K.S: You can use `objc_getProperty` and `objc_setProperty` http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html

Answer (score -3):

if you do not specify the `readonly` with **property** declaration then Compiler will produce the **getter** and **setter** and be as below.

```
setter  ---> setValue:
[self setValue:@"setter"];

getter -----> Value,

NSString* myValue =  [self Value];
```

Compilar will not produce the **setter** function for the property which you have declared with  `readonly`.

### `atomic` are thread safe whereas `nonatomic` is not.

Comment: I am more interested in the atomic part of the story, and if there is a detailed code for that, that'll be more clear. I will update my question a bit for that. :-)

Comment: Atomic properties are not thread-safe, they are atomic, hence the name. Being atomic is not the same as being thread-safe. Being atomic only means, that the system makes setting/getting a property value always works as getting/setting an `int` (which would usually not be the case for more complex data types). Since they are atomic, you can not "mash their values up" if you access them by multiple threads concurrently, but that's because they are atomic, not because they are thread-safe.

Comment: Setting properties as atomic makes accessing them, be it for reading or writing, thread-safe. It does not ensure thread-safety in a class-wide context but is a tool to achieve it.