# Calling "super init" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, retain, autorelease

While reading about classes in Objective-C I found that in some cases people advice that when implementing the `init` method to do it as:

```
- (id) init {

    if ( self = [super init] ) { 

        ...
    }

    return self; 
}
```

While others don't refer this. Which one is correct one?

Also, when defining setters most of the times they simply consist in an assignment but sometimes they appear as:

```
- (void) setCaption: (NSString*)input {

  [caption autorelease];
  [input retain];
  caption = input;
}
```

Once again, which one is the best approach? Does ARC has some effect on this? If I use ARC, I don't need to use `autorelease`as above?

thanks!

Comment: With ARC you don't have to care about memory management, all methods like retain, release, autorelease and dealloc are forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from Apple's [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html):

> There are several critical rules to follow when implementing an
>   init... method that serves as a class’s sole initializer or, if there
>   are multiple initializers, its designated initializer (described in
>   “Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer”):
>
> - Always invoke the superclass (super) initializer first.
> - Check the object returned by the superclass. If it is nil, then initialization cannot proceed; return nil to the receiver.
> - When initializing instance variables that are references to objects, retain or copy the object as necessary (in memory-managed
>     code).
> - After setting instance variables to valid initial values, return self unless:
>
>   - It was necessary to return a substituted object, in which case release the freshly allocated object first (in memory-managed code).
>   - A problem prevented initialization from succeeding, in which case return nil.

---

Concerning the second issue, you typically don't have to implement the accessor methods by hand, but in case you must or want, here's a useful reference: [Explicit getters/setters for @properties (MRC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802069/explicit-getters-setters-for-properties-mrc/21802205#21802205)

Comment: I would like to mention that one should definitely read up on objc initialiser - the docs are right of course - but IMHO a bit brief

Answer (score 1):

## 1

In general: call super.

But pay attention to dedicated initialiser and don't blindly override stuff

see: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-initializers.html

## 2

if you use arc, you don't have to do manual memory management so the setter would be one line. Most of the time auto-synthezing it is fine

Comment: the link on inits is a MUST READ for this ;)

Answer (score -1):

I know that a reason calling `[super init]` is to actually initialize something belong to super class. I found a better answer given by @gabrielePetronella while I wrote my answer. Please check that out.

And, If you use ARC, you don't use a set of memory management methods such as `[release]`, `[autorelease]`. Even though you try to use those methods, Xcode sends you a compile error.

Comment: you don't link an answer and don't provide any new insides I fear.